# show accented character in search windows 8 app - Diacritic Insensitive Search

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, dictionary, windows-8

I have a windows 8 application.The problem is, if I type in the search bar the letter " e " it will only show me words starting with the letter " e " correctly, neglecting all the words starting/having the letter " é". how can i show results of " e " and " é " when the user presses " e ". Practically like all the french dictionaries work!

This is how I filter the words when the user presses any letter :

```
private void inputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = inputTextBox.Text.Replace("'", "’");

    isTyping = true;
    setListSource(currentText, null);
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using CurrentCulture?